# Espresso ActivityTestRule won't restart Activity after first test

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am having trouble running Espresso test. After my first test is run, it will fail launch the next intent and reach a timeout.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 
cmp=se.liu.ida.sambandssystem/.Authentication } within 45 seconds. 
Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount 
of time? There could be an animation or something constantly 
repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on 
creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time 
the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 
1492675509022 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 
1492675551675. If these numbers are the same your activity might be 
hogging the event queue...
```

I have tried different kinds of TestRules, even a custom one with explicit `finishActivity()` and `relaunchActivity()` methods, but it didn't work. The application is doing network calls, and I have tried to disconnect it after the first test, but that didn't work either. Anyone have an idea of how to force quit the application after each launch?

Here is some example code from tests:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class AuthenticationTest {

    private String mNFC, mPassword;
    private int nrOfruns;
    private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;
    private AuthenticationUtil util;

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<Authentication> mActivityTestRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<Authentication>(
                    Authentication.class,
                    false, //Inital touchmode
                    true  //LaunchActivity
            );

    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        mIdlingResource = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();       
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() throws Service.NotInitializedException {
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        }
        Log.d("TEST", "Unregistering Espresso Idling resource");
    }

    @Before
    public void initValidLogin() throws InterruptedException, Service.NotInitializedException {
        nrOfruns = 10;
        validNFC = "11111111";
        validPassword = "password";
        util = new AuthenticationUtil(); //Espresso code for clicking login buttons like a user would
        util.logOutIfLocked();
    }


    @Test
    public void validAuthenticationTest() throws Exception {
        Log.d("TEST", "Valid authentication test...");
        util.authenticate(validNFC, validPassword);

        //Log out after successful log in
        onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(actionOpenDrawer());
        onView(withId(R.id.nav_view))
                .perform(NavigationViewActions.navigateTo(R.id.nav_logout));
        onView(withText("Log out")).perform(click());

        Log.d("TEST", "Valid authentication test complete");

    }

    @Test
    public void invalidLogInTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Log.d("TEST","Invalid authentication test...");
        HashMap<String, String> invalidLogins = createInvalidLogins(nrOfruns);

        for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> invalidLogin : invalidLogins.entrySet()){
            util.authenticate(invalidLogin.getKey(), invalidLogin.getValue());
        }
    }
```

The tests works if launched separately, but I would like if the tests could be placed in the same class but different methods.

**Edit:** The problem was our application created many toast messages that got queued up, prohibiting the next intent to launch. After removing all toasts the tests worked as intended.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue, but without toasts. I have no idea what's blocking the intents.

Comment: could you solve the problem? actually i am getting these error